# How to iterate over multiline variable in bash?

Tags: bash

Given

```
# this is programmatically generated... hard-coded here for this example
commands="\nthing1@this is thing 1!\nthing2@this is thing 2!"

while read -r line; do
  cmd=$(printf "$line" | cut -d'@' -f1 | tr -d '\n')
  desc=$(printf "$line" | cut -d'@' -f2 | tr -d '\n')

  printf '  %-20s %s\n' "$cmd" "$desc"
done <<< "$commands"
```

I'd expect that to output

```
  thing1        this is thing1!
  thing2        this is thing2!
```

Instead I get

```
  thing1thing2        this is thing1!this is thing2!
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to `read` over the newlines, so I can then `cut` on `@` and `printf` accordingly.

Comment: how about `echo "$commands" | awk -F@ '{printf("%20s\t%s\n",$1, $2)}'` One process for all data, not ~8 processes per line ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Ahh, think that needs to be `echo -e`... but yeah, didn't think of `awk`. I'm no bash guru, so apologies about the abusing of processes per line. :-o Mind posting your solution as an answer?

Comment: Are you autogenerating the string with the two-character sequence `\\`, `n`, or with real newlines?

Comment: In general, there's almost never a reason to use `cut` like this.  Let read do the parsing for you with `while IFS=@ read -r cmd desc _; do ...`

Comment: @rici Yes, see the comment in my code above: `this is programmatically generated`

Comment: @neezer: that doesn't answer my question :) The two-character sequence `\\` `n` (as shown in your sample code) is *not* a newline so  `read -r` reads the entire string as a single line (which is what it is). That fact, plus the fact that your example doesn't work because of the use of unescaped exclamation points, makes me wonder if you really meant those to be newlines.

Comment: @rici Sorry, not sure what you mean then by `\\` `n` (or however you're formatting it). I'm building the string by interpolating values into a variable incrementally, wedging `\n` in-between manually. But really, @shellter 's `awk` (with my `echo -e` edit) solution is working perfectly for me atm.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

input="\nthing1@this is thing 1!\nthing2@this is thing 2!"

# echo replaces '\n's with real new-lines
# readarray -t loads the multiline string into an array
readarray -t array <<< $(echo -e "${input}")

# loop it
for command in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "${command}"
done
```

Comment: Be very wary of `eval`. What if `input` happened to include `rm -rf /*`?

Comment: How do you get around `-bash: !\nthing2@this: event not found`?

Comment: Wow, I don't get it. Posted my whole script.

Comment: Without single-quoting `input`, the `!` isn't allowed. (that may be a typo in the question itself) Simply try `input="\nthing1@this is thing 1!\nthing2@this is thing 2!"; echo -e "$input"` Then *single-quote* it and try again.

Comment: ! is never a special symbol.
I single-quoted, nothing changed, because it does not matter.
Your version of bash?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` See [**In bash, how do I escape an exclamation mark?**](https://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark)

Comment: It's 'how I escape', not 'why I escape' :)
In any case, it works.

Comment: Yes, I'm not picking on you. I like your use of `readarray`. My point being if `input` is not single quoted, they will receive the `event not found?` error. `!` being a *Reserved Word* in bash.

Comment: As I remember, ! is used for executing commands from history and won't happen if the exclamation mark is not a part of a command.
The author won't be able to insert variables into his string if it is single quoted.

Comment: Starting in `bash` 4.4, you can use `${input@E}` in place of `$(echo -e "$input")`.

Comment: `!` is not a reserved word, but a word starting with `!` is subject to history expansion if enabled with `set -h` (which is the default in an interactive shell).

Comment: `man bash` calls `'!'` one of the `"RESERVED WORDS"`, maybe there is another term of common use applied to it, but according to `man bash` *Reserved words are words that have a special meaning to the shell. (various first word and third word use in `for` or `case` conditions)*

Comment: @chepner excellent comment on `${parameter@operator}` *Parameter  transformation* - that is the first I've heard of that, but will add it to the toolbox. `Q, E, P, A, a` operators are available.

Comment: My apologies; I never noticed `!` hiding out at beginning of the list of reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

according to your question, it seems like bash does not interpret any of `\n \t \f e.t.c` when used with here strings.This might be what you want, it might be bad practice. And an exclamation mark wrapped around double quote will result in an error, because bash will try to evaluate it as an event ( command executed on the shell at some point ) , so you have to escape that ( when used from the terminal )

```
commands="\nthing1@this is thing 1\!\nthing2@this is thing 2!"

while read line;do
   // do your stuff here
line <<< $( echo -e "${commands}" )  # -e switch tells the echo command to honour all back slashes . The same behaviour can be achieved with `shopt -s xpg_echo` ( you have to remove -e switch whenever you do that )
```

*noise:* **Note: When used from the terminal:** if you look closely at the command variable i did not backslash the "!" this is because it is not proceeded by any value, so bash will not try to locate the preceded value as an event.

check the history expansion section of bash man page for more information on that if you wish